# refresh pie chart with ajax

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i use jsf , primefaces to create a web page 
I want update my pie chart using a commandButton which after user enter paramters that using in my query to fetch data 
I don't know how to make it

can you help me how to pass the parameters to the method that creates the chart and after click the commandButtom the chart updated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.yourMethod}" value="Click Me">
    <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.onButtonPress}" update="component_id" />
</p:commandButton>
```

or

```
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.yourMethod}" value="Click Me" update="component_id" />
```

If your component is in another form, write it like this: `:form_id:component_id`.

If you use actionListener instead of action, you must put this parameter to your method: `ActionEvent event`. The full class name is `javax.faces.event.ActionEvent`.